# Django ORM update field to NOW() returning 0 error

Tags: django

I am trying to loop through a list of results, process them, then update their "updated_details" field.

```
users_to_update = TiktokUser.objects.filter(Q(updated_details__lt=datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(weeks=1)) | Q(updated_details__isnull=True))[0:1]
    for user_to_update in users_to_update:
        print(datetime.now())
        user_to_update.updated_details = datetime.now()
        user_to_update.save()
```

The idea being that on each loop, i set the `updated_details` to the current timestamp. My `print()` statement here correctly prints out the current date and time, however when I update the record itself and save, I get the following error:

```
['“0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000” value has the correct format (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ]) but it is an invalid date/time.']
```

Which implies to me it is attempting to set it to 0.

My model definition is:

```
class User(models.Model):
    ...
    updated_details = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    ...
```

How do I get Django to set the field to the current `DateTime`?

Comment: have you set any date time format in settings.py ??

Answer (score 0):

You are using python datetime, please use django datetime it's based upon settings file of your django project

```
from django.utils.timezone import now
users_to_update = TiktokUser.objects.filter(Q(updated_details__lt=datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(weeks=1)) | Q(updated_details__isnull=True))[0:1]
for user_to_update in users_to_update:
        user_to_update.updated_details = now()
        user_to_update.save()
```